# asp.net Identity - GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync Method When Passed to View Token Changes?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-identity

When I use the usermanager to generate a password reset token, once this gets passed to the razor view the token is changing.

An example is:

```
 var resetToken = await userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(userId);

            if (registerSuccess)
            {
                var model = new ResetModel { Token = resetToken, UserId = userId };               
                return this.View(model);          
            }
```

I can see when debugging that the value of the reset token is

AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE/Cl+sBAAAAmfrU4hd3Q0WLiANC7DsekQAAAAACAAAAAAADZgAAwAAAABAAAAB1Q/FgOVgsh+0SsLLYSKrFAAAAAASAAACgAAAAEAAAAFMVfXSy24PLGHSoIqFO/YRAAAAAYll/7E8QwrH5JEfhMKGVHNe4CZM3TFWVL4lRE7Jhm/I6CKkTdloHofac054Ergy7BtwtV9OM7ila3f/ti90iDBQAAABAfR8pdGZ2eBXq/sGw0qVP6PQlWg==

But then once this rendered on the view it has changed to

AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE/Cl+sBAAAAmfrU4hd3Q0WLiANC7DsekQAAAAACAAAAAAADZgAAwAAAABAAAACDU0qQzkc65kQa58ift5NBAAAAAASAAACgAAAAEAAAAGGy5Flp6xtR7cGZkvRoNNpAAAAAha1iP7uXqD6KSKbWBOfdXM1KaZnOekiYTSad6/zkejoCk5cDd1FK/JdxKS0Rx9rHeqTJpZkzeEmh5HI3//cLixQAAAAJFOivgVuhoOXTMZMeY+AlLzmifQ==

The view code looks like:

```
 @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Token)
```

I'm at a total loss whats going off here. Does anyone know whats happening? Why is the token changing once it's rendered to the view?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Are you sure there isn't something else happening here?

Comment: I sure that there is nothing else happening. The only way that I managed to get around it was to not use the Html Helper @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Token) and instead put this in the view  <input type="hidden" id="token" name="token" value="@Model.Token" /> Any ideas why the helper is messing up the token???

Comment: I tested using a HiddenFor and it was still the same. What version of MVC are you using?

Comment: old Q, but are you calling it twice? it will return a new value each time.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add Url-Encoding for the token if it is passed to urls:

```
var resetToken = await userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(userId);
resetToken = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(resetToken);
```

Otherwise browser messes with the special symbols that can be present in the token.

If you print in a view, you need to turn off HtmlEncoding via `Html.Raw`:

```
<input type="hidden" value="@Html.Raw(Model.Token)" name="Token" />
```